# How do I create a two color content with a slash separator?

Tags: css, shapes

My code like this :

```
    <v-col
      sm="3"
      class="contain-left"
    >
        <div id="rectangle">

        </div>
        <div id="triangle-topright">

        </div>
    </v-col>
```

My codepen like this : https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/MWwGygw

Can it be custom by CSS or have to pass image?

I try use css, but there exist 2 element. there are rectangle element and triangle top right element

I want to make it only 1 element. Because I want to display slides inside that content. So I want to combine it into 1 element

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As I interpret your question, you want to create a box with a diagonal line through it.

```css
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, #d3e3ff 50%, #eff6ff 50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using multiple backgrounds on one element, values are to be adjusted according to what you want

```css
div {
  background: 
  linear-gradient(25deg, #00000000 49%, #d3e3ff 50%) 0 0/100% 50% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(#eff6ff, #eff6ff) 0 0/50% 100% no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @SuccessMan **I want to make it only 1 element. Because I want to display slides inside that content. So I want to combine it into 1 element** This is exactly what you asked for i don't understand what mean  by *same layout as in codepen*